# Updating 40 million mysql cells at once

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is it feasible to update about 40 million cells of data in mysql at once? When I say update I mean taking a table and copying a portion of it to another, much larger, table. It would have to happen once every hour.

Comment: The sky is the limit, especially when they are no limits like in our question. _40 million cells_, but what is a cell? _At once_, what is at once? _Much larger table_, what is a larger table ? Every hour, why? Your question should basically be 10 times longer than in its actual state in order for us to answer anything.  Updating 40 million rows is just the normal job for any RDBMS running on a decent hardware. However is it the right thing to do and how to do it rightly are the real questions and are not answerable in the actual state of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for it would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO much_larger_table (cols...)
  SELECT cols... FROM a_table
  WHERE ...conditions...;
```

(I am using some placeholders because you haven't described your tables.)

There's no limit to the number of rows you can copy using syntax like this, but there's a practical limit to how many you want to do in one batch.

It will take time of course. We can't predict how long it will take, because it depends on a lot of factors specific to your server and your tables. It's possible that it will take more than the hour in between your scheduled tasks.

The risk is that an INSERT...SELECT statement like this locks the rows as they are read from the origin table. This means no session can modify those rows, and maybe cannot even insert or update other rows in that table, depending on gap locking.

I tell the developers at my company to limit batches to 1000 rows per transaction. This allows each transaction to finish quickly, reduces the number of rows locked and the duration of the lock, and allows MySQL garbage collection to continue.

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful to know